# Getting url param is not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have this URL and I have no idea how to get that woNum param in Angular controller...

Why $location.search.woNum is undefined in my controllers constructor ??

> Inbox/Detail?woNum=CIB12717559

```
class DetailController {
    data: any;
    message: string;

    static $inject: string[] = ["DataService", "$location", "$filter"];

    constructor(private dataService: DataService, private $location, private $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
        var woNum = $location.search.woNum;
        this.message = "Please wait, loading the work order...";
        this.getWorkOrderDetail(woNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $routeParams: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Inject $routeParams in the controller and try printing it to see if you can get it:

```
console.log($routeParams);
```

Hope it helps =)